# How to Get File from Input type=file

Tags: html, reactjs

I am using reactjs and in my render I have this

```
            <div className="file-field input-field col s12">
                <div className="btn">
                    <span>File</span>
                    <input type="file" accept=".csv"  onChange={ (event) => this.fileUploaded(event) }/>
                 </div>
                <div className="file-path-wrapper">
                <input className="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload A Signle csv file" />
            </div>
```

I then have

```
   fileUploaded(event) {
        var reader = new FileReader();


    }
```

but I don't see anything about files in event. Am I passing in the wrong thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to reference the element which has the file list.

```
console.log(event.target.files)
```

Comment: So you are saying react does not have target in their event object?